# Display 5 Digit Zip in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a devise user model, and part of the information I ask of them is their 5 digit zip code. If their zip code is 08601, then, when they go to edit their user settings, they see their zip code as 8601, without the 0 in front. Is there a way to format the zip code that devise displays in the account settings (something like "%05d")? Here is what I have in that field so far:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :zip_code %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :zip_code, class: "form-control", autofocus: true %>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem might be in your database column data type**

Since you are using ZIP code in your form I think you have used zip_code column in database as integer that's why you are getting this. Change data type of column to string and then try saving your data.

**If you want to keep data type integer**

If you do so you need to change your zip_code to string everytime you use it and add 00 before zip_code. This is not a good approach of programming and may be the problem later.

**But You can do this in model**

```
def self.zip_code_string
   @zip = self.zip_code.to_s
   "00"+@zip
end
```

**And to display or use**

```
@user.zip_code_string
```

will work

Comment: Yes, the zip code field is an integer. Is there I way I could keep it this way, and simply format it in this devise form? I only ask this because I validate that the zip code is an integer when a new user signs up. If there is no way to do this, then I will change the data type to a string

Comment: Ok, thanks. It seems like I will just change the data type then. :)